# Python - Pymongo MongoDB 3.4 - NumberDecimal

Tags: python, mongodb, numbers, decimal, pymongo

i am using mongodb 3.4 in order to insert proper prices to my database..

According to:

```
https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/bson-decimal128/decimal128.rst#reading-from-extended-json
```

i used this in my python code:

```
'credits': {'$numberDecimal': Decimal128('9.99')},
```

but throws:

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key '$numberDecimal' must not start with '$'
```

So what is the correct syntax for inserting numberdecimal in mongodb using python ?

thanks and greetings

Answer (score 3):

Simply this:

```
collection.insert_one({'credits': Decimal128('9.99')})
```

(The "$numberDecimal" syntax is for expressing a decimal number within a JSON string. But you're not using JSON at all.)

Answer (score -1):

The link you provided tells you about **reading** from extended JSON. If you want to insert it as a decimal, you should just use:

```
{ 'credits': '{0:.2f}'.format(9.99) }
```

The `'{0:.2f}'.format(9.99)` part will format the number you pass (in this case 9.99) to include 2 decimals every time. So `'{0:.2f}'.format(9)` should result in 9.00 in your database.

Comment: your syntax works for 9.99... but i need it always to insert a double, also for "9" and  "9.00" , you know?